# Inverse image of a sheaf associated to a module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $f:\operatorname{Spec}B \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ be a morphism of spectra, how do I show, for any $A$-module $M$, we have $f^*(\tilde{M})$ is isomorphic to $\widetilde{M\otimes_{A}B}$?

This question was asked here [Inverse image of the sheaf associated to a module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/inverse-image-of-the-sheaf-associated-to-a-module). In Martin's answer, he used the adjointness property. However he also mentioned that one can use the complicated ad hoc definition to compute this inverse image.

How can one prove this without using adjointness? Can I compute directly, for example, the module $f^*(\tilde{M})(D(g))$ for any $g\in B$ and then compare it with that of $(M\otimes_{A}B)_g$?

Comment: By "complicated ad hoc definition" do you mean $f^{-1}(\widetilde{M})\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}} \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec B}}$?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, that is the definition of inverse image.

Comment: Just checking - whether that's complicated or ad hoc is a matter of opinion, and I wanted to make sure I knew exactly what definition you wanted before potentially writing an answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer about this last year [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673658/why-is-the-pullback-between-affine-varieties-of-a-quasi-coherent-sheaf-quasi-c/3693163#3693163) which might be helpful.